# How to set up OpenI plugin for Mondrian

Tags: mondrian

I want to replace `jPivot` with `OpenI` in `Mondrian OLAP Server`. I have deployed `Mondrian` which comes with `jPivot` as default  sample distribution in `Glassfish` server and it was successful. Now I need to replace this with `OpenI` Which is having nice UI and features (I think this framework is built upon `jPivot`).

Comment: I don't use OpenI before, but if your Mondrian OLAP Server is ready, you may try a pure javascript solution at [webpivottable.com](http://webpivottable.com) and [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo)

Comment: I've tried `webpivottable` as you suggested with my Mondrian URL in the demo page. But this always shows `time out` error.

Comment: Your URL should be a Internet link which can be access from webpivottable demo server.  You can try download the application , install it on your local machine follow the [document](http://webpivottable.com/documents), or ask support from the forum.

Comment: And make sure you are using XMLA URL, for Mondrian, it should be something like http://host:port/mondrian/xmla , depends on your Mondrian installation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are saying. I'll explain my configurations. I've a Mondrian XMLA URL, like `localhost:8080/mondrian/xmla`. Now I need to get this into `webpivottable`. I've downloaded this and copied `public\brightsea` directory to my app directory. Then I've added dojo.js like in the docs. Now I can access the page like in demo. But when I try to load data using XMLA URL it throws an error `Access to restricted URI denied` ie, `POST localhost:8080/wpt/xmlaProxy 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: proxy error:  This is because "Same Origin Policy" for Ajax call. We need a proxy at server side if we make a ajax call to request a resource which  not in the same domain as our web server. In our independent application, we have a node.js proxy  /wpt/xmlaProxy. if you integrate it into your own web server and your web server is not the same as mondrain server (same host and same port), you need provide your own proxy and set proxy url in customOptions.

Comment: If your web server and your Mondrian is at the same server with same host and port, you don't need xmlaProxy, you can set options.server.xmlaProxy the same as Mondrian Xmla URL, in your case, you can set it to '/mondrian/xmla' . If you still have problem, ask at their support forum.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid too many comments in the question, I create an answer at here:

You can try a pure javascript [webpivottable](http://webpivottable.com) . This is a client side solution and no dependence to any back end technology. Here is [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents)

The latest version (version 1.6) can enable/disable proxy at UI now, so no problem to integrate it into local Mondrian server(just disable proxy at UI).

For cross domain access(web server and Mondrian server not at the same host:port), you can set options.server.xmlaProxy in the customOptions to your http proxy at your web server.